# Pandas: linearly interpolate multiple steps between multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I've been looking over multiple versions of my problem on here, and can't find an answer for what I'm trying to do.

**Problem:**
I have a Pandas dataframe with a bunch of decimal-number data, collected over multiple iterations of an experiment (each row), for multiple wavelengths of light (each column). These wavelength intervals are the column headers, and the interval between the wavelengths/columns is currently 2.5, due to the limitation of our machine.

I now need to calculate what the values of each row should be at wavelength intervals of 0.1, instead of 2.5. This will require me to create new column headers with a spacing of 0.1 (so 24 new columns between each of my current columns), and then do a linear interpolation of the values in each row at each 0.1 step.

Can anyone help? I'm at a complete loss of how to do this.

**What I've got so far:**

```
# data_in = my original Panda dataframe with experiment data.
# wavelengths (column headers) go from 400 to 900 in 2.5nm intervals.
# I want 400 to 900 in 0.1 nm intervals.

# Create a copy dataframe for generating the interpolated columns, 
# copying the structure of the original file for the first 3 columns.
# (I need the first 3 columns intact for an unimportant reason)
data_interp = data_in[data_in.columns[0:3]].copy()

# Interpolate 400 to 900 nm in 0.1 nm steps for the column headers.
wave_array = np.linspace(400, 900, num=5000, endpoint=True)

# Import the interpolated numpy array as column headers in the new panda dataframe.
data_interp = pd.concat([data_interp,pd.DataFrame(columns=wave_array)])

# Use the pandas 'update' function to map any matching instances of columns and their data   
# from 'data_in' to 'data_interp' (ie, import all the 2.5 nm interval data from  
# the old dataframe to their proper place in the new dataframe).
data_interp.update(data_in)
```

Now I have a new Panda dataframe (data_interp) that contains all of my original, 2.5 nm interval data, as well as a TON of empty columns with 0.1 nm interval headers.

I need to populate all these empty cells with interpolated data, calculated from the data that's present at 2.5 nm intervals.

Any help is welcome, thanks.

**Edit 1: Here are a couple photos of my input dataframe (data_in), and my new interpolated dataframe (data_interp).**

`data_in`:

[image: data_in]

`data_interp`:

[image: data_interp]

**Edit 2: A miniaturised example.**

```
# Mini data.
data_mini = [[10, 13, 11], [15, 14, 15], [19, 18, 22]] 

# Convert to pandas dataframe
data_mini_pd = pd.DataFrame(data_mini, columns = [400, 402.5, 405])  

# Copy new dataframe based on original dataframe
data_mini_pd_interp = data_mini_pd[data_mini_pd.columns[0:0]].copy()

# Interpolate 400 to 405 nm in 0.1 nm steps for the column headers.
wave_array_mini = np.linspace(400, 405, num=50, endpoint=True)

# Round all numbers to 1 decimal place, to prevent float placeholder overflow
# when importing to panda column headers.
wave_array_mini_round = np.around(wave_array_mini, decimals=1)

# Import the interpolated numpy array as column headers in the new panda dataframe.
data_mini_pd_interp = pd.concat([data_mini_pd_interp,pd.DataFrame(columns=wave_array_mini_round)])

# Use the pandas 'update' function to map any matching instances of columns and their data from 'data_in' to 'data_interp' (ie, import all the 2.5 nm interval
# data from  the old dataframe to their proper place in the new dataframe).
data_mini_pd_interp.update(data_mini_pd)
```

Comment: Could you provide us some sample data (a few original rows) and show what you currently get?

Comment: @SergeBallesta  I've added links to screenshots of my two dataframes.

Comment: We cannot reproduce anything from images... You should give copyable data. BTW, why is the dataframe *column wise*? It is more common to have a DateTimeIndex labeling the rows.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Okay, I've included a mini example of the data I was working with.

I have no control over the formatting of the incoming data - it's how I get it. The data is organised by a DateTime index labelling the rows, as you said (I cut off those columns during display because it includes some sensitive information).

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit ugly but should do the trick:

```
##generate data
nrows = 100
cols = [x/10.0 for x in range(0, 100, 25)]
data = {c: np.random.uniform(0, 1, nrows) for c in cols}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

```
 interpolation_steps = 25 
 dfs = []
 #Iterate on each interpolation pair(start, end)
 for col_ind in range(0, len(cols)-1):
     ##Using list comparison to iterate on each row, performin np.linspace on relevant columns values and creating a dataframe based on these results(along with column names).
     inter_df = pd.DataFrame([np.linspace(x, y, interpolation_steps) for x, y in 
     zip(df.iloc[:, col_ind], df.iloc[:, col_ind + 1])],
            columns=[i/10 for i in range(int(df.columns[col_ind]*10), 
            int(df.columns[col_ind+1]*10), 1)])
     dfs.append(inter_df)

  ##Merging interpolated dataframes back together into one big dataframe
  full_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
  ##adding last column because interpolated without it
  last_col = df.columns[-1]
  full_df.loc[:, last_col] = df[last_col]
  print(full_df.head(3).T)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like it might be what I need. I'm grabbing a meal and will look at this when I'm back to my desk.

Thank you either way, for taking the time to write this out!

Comment: Checking back in now that I've had some more time with this. This worked exactly like I needed, even after I adjusted things for my proper file format/columns - thank you!  


I'm coming from MATLAB, where loops need to be written more explicitly (/clunkily?) than Python - the compressed shorthand is still something that I'm getting used to. If you see this and are willing to spend some more time, I wouldn't mind an explanation of what exactly is going on with your "inter_df = ..." command.  

If not I'll keep trying to read up, and thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would transpose the matrix and cheat the (new) index to make it a DatetimeIndex - the absolute values will be off by a 1000 factor, but it does not matter for the data. That way it becomes possible to just resample the dataframe with a different frequency.

After that, it would be enough to convert the index back to floats and transpose again to get your expected result.

Starting with your `data_mini_dp`, it could be:

```
df = data_mini_pd.T.set_index(pd.to_datetime(
    (data_mini_pd.columns * 10).astype(int), format='%f')
                              ).resample('100000ns').interpolate()

df.index = df.index.strftime('%f').astype('float64')/1000

resul = df.T
```

giving:

```
   400.0  400.1  400.2  400.3  400.4  400.5  400.6  400.7  400.8  400.9  401.0  401.1  401.2  401.3  401.4  401.5  401.6  401.7  401.8  401.9  402.0  402.1  402.2  402.3  402.4  402.5  402.6  402.7  402.8  402.9  403.0  403.1  403.2  403.3  403.4  403.5  403.6  403.7  403.8  403.9  404.0  404.1  404.2  404.3  404.4  404.5  404.6  404.7  404.8  404.9  405.0
0   10.0  10.12  10.24  10.36  10.48   10.6  10.72  10.84  10.96  11.08   11.2  11.32  11.44  11.56  11.68   11.8  11.92  12.04  12.16  12.28   12.4  12.52  12.64  12.76  12.88   13.0  12.92  12.84  12.76  12.68   12.6  12.52  12.44  12.36  12.28   12.2  12.12  12.04  11.96  11.88   11.8  11.72  11.64  11.56  11.48   11.4  11.32  11.24  11.16  11.08   11.0
1   15.0  14.96  14.92  14.88  14.84   14.8  14.76  14.72  14.68  14.64   14.6  14.56  14.52  14.48  14.44   14.4  14.36  14.32  14.28  14.24   14.2  14.16  14.12  14.08  14.04   14.0  14.04  14.08  14.12  14.16   14.2  14.24  14.28  14.32  14.36   14.4  14.44  14.48  14.52  14.56   14.6  14.64  14.68  14.72  14.76   14.8  14.84  14.88  14.92  14.96   15.0
2   19.0  18.96  18.92  18.88  18.84   18.8  18.76  18.72  18.68  18.64   18.6  18.56  18.52  18.48  18.44   18.4  18.36  18.32  18.28  18.24   18.2  18.16  18.12  18.08  18.04   18.0  18.16  18.32  18.48  18.64   18.8  18.96  19.12  19.28  19.44   19.6  19.76  19.92  20.08  20.24   20.4  20.56  20.72  20.88  21.04   21.2  21.36  21.52  21.68  21.84   22.0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for this. It's certainly more concise than the other solution, although I'm wary of the DateTime conversion. Is all the lifting done by "data_mini_pd.resample(..." and "data_mini_pd.interpolate()"? And ".resample" requires a DateTime stamp to work rather than a float?

I'm just amazed that it handles all the data without explicitly specifying rows, which columns to interp between, the fact that intermediate columns need to be created, etc.